# Can you queue Build-Deploy-Test workflows in TFS 2012 or 2015?

Tags: tfs-2015, build-process-template

the question I am referring to is this one: [Can you queue Build-Deploy-Test workflows in TFS 2010?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20516617/can-you-queue-build-deploy-test-workflows-in-tfs-2010)

It is stated, that with TFS 2010 it's not possible to do it (other than by hand). But what about TFS 2012/2015? Is there anything new that one can use to queue such a workflow as of today?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can queue multiple Build-Deploy-Test build workflows on the same lab environment all the time, but you have to wait for the previous build-deploy-test completes, then queue the next one.

The referred case gives out a solution to automatically start the build until the configured lab environment becomes available when he queued multiple builds, by customizing the lab process template.

In a word, no matter which version of TFS you are using, you can queue multiple Build-Deploy-Test build workflows on the same lab environment, but it's better not to queue them at same time.

Comment: That was exactly my point (and the point of the other author). We don't want those workflows to start simultaneously. The preferred scenraio would be, taht TFS queues the one build that came later and waits for the other one to finish. The question is, if theres something else you can do, other than customizing the process template manually, because its (maybe) not the nicest solution.

Comment: If you have only one build agent, the latter build will wait until the previous build finishes, but this only for build part. There is not a default setting to make the latter Build-Deploy-Test workflows wait until the previous one completely finishes when you queue multiple builds. You may consider setting up multiple build agents and test agents if you have the requirement of queue multiple builds in a short time.